# Multiple If conditions in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I clearly have a syntax issue and would like to know where am I magically missing the point. Got tired of trying to find the answer so I decided to ask.

Code just wants to check if `X` is not any of three specific variables, and if not then `P = 3`, other `P` will equal `1` or `2` based on a combo box result.

I tried using Or statements with this and no luck.

```
 If X <> 15 Then
     P = "3"
 Else
     If X <> 18 Then
         P = "3"
     End If
         Else
             If X <> 20 Then
                 P = "3"
             End If
 ElseIf ComboBox <> "Other Condition" Then
     P = 1
     Else: P = 2
 End If
```

Comment: Have you tried `elseif`? Edit: not sure how you did `or` but should be `If X <> 15 or X <> 18 or X <> 20 Then`

Comment: As I mentioned below, the reason it doesnt work is Or basically says "this or that" when in reality i needed a "this And That." I got to caught up in trying to make the wrong thing work and as a result gloriously "missed the obvious."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
If X <> 2 And X <> 3 And X <> 4 Then
    P = 3
ElseIf ComboBox <> "OtherCondition" Then
    P = 1
Else
    P = 2
End If
```

Comment: This is the exact same thing I tried but with Or statements. The reason why I was dumb was my reasoning needed to check if each statements met the criteria not one or the other (or the other). I guess I just needed a fresh set of eyes. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
If x = 15 Or x = 18 Or x = 20 Then
    If ComboBox = "Other Condition" Then
        P = 2
    Else
        P = 1
    End If
Else
    P = 3
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer

```
If x <> 15 and x <> 18 and x <> 20 then
    P = 3
ElseIf ComboBox <> "Other Condition" then
    P = 1
Else
    P = 2
End If
```

Your version has and `Else` followed by an `End If`, which is incorrect syntax. This version is more succinct and easier to read, IMHO.

Comment: I agree with your code, but not your reasoning. The reason it doesn't work isn't because there's an `Else` ... `End If`, as that is syntactically correct. The reason it breaks is because there is `Else` ... `Else`, and to dot the i, an `ElseIf` after that. There can be only 1 `Else` and it has to be at the end of the loop.

Comment: Thanks. I think that is what I meant to say and got to typing too quickly.